# How to handle scientific notation in addition in array_sum etc

Tags: php

How to add all values in this array?

If the value with the scientific notation `4.400...E+26` is commented out the result is `10171018899000`

```
$list = [
    700,
    700,
    200,
    700,
    2853300,
    595300,
    4736700,
    1700,
    4.4002258020009E+26,
    200,
    39800,
    171002250300,
    8410600,
    100,
    1000,
    10000000000800,
    100,
    6000,
    700,
    100
];
print_r($list);
$sum = array_sum($list);
echo "sum: $sum\n";
$sum = (int)$sum;
echo "sum: $sum\n";
```

output

```
sum: 4.400225802001E+26
sum: -2402111299539435520
```

Comment: Sounds like it's down to PHP handles ints(https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) and the limits and how it interprets the values when you reach those bounds.

Comment: A simple version of your question is: `echo (int)4.4002258020009E+26;`. See: https://3v4l.org/8Bign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you're getting is not "completely wrong." It's in scientific notation. The number 4.4002258020009E+26 is a very large number that is expressed in scientific notation (also known as exponential notation) for conciseness.

In scientific notation, 4.4002258020009E+26 is equivalent to 4.4002258020009 * 10^26, which is an incredibly large number.

When you're printing the sum, PHP is using scientific notation for the output because it's a convenient way to represent extremely large numbers.

If you want to see the result in standard decimal notation, you can use number_format() to format the output:

```
$list = [
    700,
    700,
    200,
    700,
    2853300,
    595300,
    4736700,
    1700,
    4.4002258020009E+26,
    200,
    39800,
    171002250300,
    8410600,
    100,
    1000,
    10000000000800,
    100,
    6000,
    700,
    100
];

$sum = array_sum($list);
// Format as integer with comma as thousands separator
$formatted_sum = number_format($sum, 0, '.', ','); 
$formatted_sum_without_comma = number_format($sum, 0, '.', ''); 

echo "Sum: $formatted_sum";
//Result: Sum: 44,002,258,020,009,299,302,508,000

echo '<br>';

echo "Sum: $formatted_sum_without_comma ";
//Result: Sum: 44002258020009299302508000
```

This will give you the sum in a more human-readable format. Also if the sum is still too large, you may encounter limitations in PHP's floating-point precision.

Answer (score 0):

You could use utilize [bcmath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php) for large numbers and high preceision calculation. With the help of [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.sprintf.php) you can easily convert the notation to a string. Instead of array sum, we can use a [reducer](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-reduce).

Demo: https://3v4l.org/ddJM9

```
echo array_reduce($list, fn($carry, $item) => bcadd($carry, sprintf('%.f', $item)), '0');

440022580200100168512040504
```